# Anglar 16: Angular Animations won't work when applied to standalone components

Tags: angular, typescript

I created an animation for my navbar and when applied directly to the component in my template as follows

```
<navbar class="navbar" [@navBarAnimation]="ShowNavBar ? 'open' : 'close'" />
```

it has no effect.  However when I wrap it in an HTML element like this

```
<section class="navbar" [@navBarAnimation]="ShowNavBar ? 'open' : 'close'">
    <navbar />
</section>
```

It works as expected.

I ran into another problem yesterday with a standalone component reading the `nativeElement` after applying a `@ViewChild()` directly onto another standalone component and decided to test the difference between standalone and the old fashioned way with an `@NgModule`.  So I made a new component naming it `TestNavComponent` along with its own module, imported the `TestNavModule` into the `AppModule` and applied the animation as follows

```
<test-nav class="navbar" [@navBarAnimation]="ShowNavBar ? 'open' : 'close'" />
```

This works as it always has in previous versions.  My `navbar` so far looks like this

***component***

```
@Component({
  selector: 'navbar',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule],
  templateUrl: './navbar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./navbar.component.css'],
})
export class NavbarComponent {

  ShowNavBar: boolean = false;

  @Output() SelectedLink: EventEmitter<string> = new EventEmitter<string>();

  constructor(private navService: NavbarService){}

  sendLink(link: string): void{
    this.SelectedLink.emit(link);
    this.navService.setCurrentPage(link);
  }

}
```

***template***

```
<nav class="srcryBox navbar">
    <svg class="wContainer">
        <g>
            <use href="#wTopA" fill="hsl(var(--gray-500), 1)" />
            <use href="#wBottomA" fill="hsl(var(--yellow-500), 1)" />
        </g>
    </svg>
    <ul id="linkContainer">
        <li><a class="navLink" href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a class="navLink" href="#">Skills</a></li>
        <li><a class="navLink" href="#">Projects</a></li>
        <li><a class="navLink" href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a class="navLink" href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="burgerMenu">
        <div class="burgerLine"></div>
        <div class="burgerLine"></div>
        <div class="burgerLine"></div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

The Animation I created looks like this

```
const NavBarAnimation = trigger('navBarAnimation', [
  state('open', style({transform: 'translateY(0)'})),
  state('close', style({transform: 'translateY(var(--tiny-2-1-))'})),
  transition('open <=> close', [animate('800ms ease-in-out')])
]);
```

I add the animation to the `animations` array in my `AppComponent` providers.  Does anybody see the problem?

Comment: You should share a bit more code, like the actual animation for example. However my guess is that the custom angular elements just don't have the same default CSS styles as regular elements do, so the animation may not appear to be working

Comment: Then why does it work on the `<test-nav />` component?  The only difference is `<test-nav>` isn't a standalone component.

Comment: It's just a guess. Like I said this is really hard to answer without any actual code.  You are showing how you use the animation but you aren't showing the actual animation, CSS, etc.  There's a lot that could be going on here and your question doesn't really give anything to go off of. You need to include a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) in your questions.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75403140/how-to-use-animations-in-an-angular-standalone-component/75403773#75403773

Comment: @ChrisBarr I added more code so you can see what I'm doing.

Comment: maybe in the standalone component don't you have to import also BrowserAnimationsModule other than CommonModule ? ...

Comment: @federicoscamuzzi I just tried that in a different project and it doesn't work.

Comment: can you just truy to add your animation to animations array in your component? (NavbarComponent)