# Angular 16 Animations Module causes NG05100 error in Stackblitz

Tags: angular, stackblitz

I can't get Angular Animations to work on my standalone components which I posted another question about [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76644552/anglar-16-angular-animations-wont-work-when-applied-to-standalone-components?noredirect=1#comment135211839_76644552) a couple weeks ago.  I'm trying to create a stackblitz demo to add to it as well as get help from others elsewhere which can be viewed [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-oo5r63?file=src%2Fmain.ts).  When I add the `BrowserAnimationsModule` to the app I get the error and it goes on to say

> Providers from the `BrowserModule` have already been loaded. If you need access to common directives such as NgIf and NgFor, import the `CommonModule` instead.

I came across another question on here about that error and the answer was to use the `NoopAnimationsModule` instead so I tried that and still got the same error.  Does anybody know why this is happening and how to fix it?

Answer (score 3):

I found the solution.  in the `main.ts` file I need to add the `provideAnimations()` method to a `providers` array in the `bootstrapApplication()` method like this

```
bootstrapApplication(App,{
  providers:[
    provideAnimations()
  ]
});
```